# UIImage created doesn't appear as I would have expected?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uigraphicscontext

iOS 10.2 swift 3.0

I am using these routines to cut, resize and recombine an image to display on an AppleTV. But despite the fact it reports the image as the correct size, it doesn't work the way I had expected/wanted.

What did I miss here?

```
func cropImage(image: UIImage, newRect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
    let img = CIImage(image: image)!.cropping(to: newRect)
    let image = UIImage(ciImage: img, scale: 1.0, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
    return image
}

func combine2LONGImage(imageUn: UIImage, imageDeux: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let size = CGSize(width: imageUn.size.width + imageDeux.size.width, height: imageUn.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    imageUn.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageUn.size.width, height: imageUn.size.height))
    imageDeux.draw(in: CGRect(x: imageUn.size.width, y: 0, width: imageDeux.size.width, height: imageDeux.size.height))
    let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}


func resizeLONGImage(image: UIImage, newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: newSize.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage!
}

 let leftSide = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:  (image2S?.size.width)!/2, height: self.view.bounds.height)


let leftImage = self.cropImage(image: image2S!, newRect: leftSide)
let rightSide = CGRect(x: (image2S?.size.width)!/2, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)

let rightImage = self.cropImage(image: image2S!, newRect: rightSide)
            print("20022017 \(leftImage) \(rightImage)")

let newLeftImage = self.resizeLONGImage(image: leftImage, newSize: CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))
let newRightImage = self.resizeLONGImage(image: rightImage, newSize: CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))
let superNewImage = self.combine2LONGImage(imageUn: newLeftImage, imageDeux: newRightImage)
print("19022017 newimage  \(self.image2P.bounds) \(leftImage.size.width) \(newLeftImage.size.height) \(superNewImage.size)")



self.image2P.image = superNewImage
self.image2P.contentMode = .left
self.image2P.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
```

The image returned is [is the correct size [twice as long as the AppleTV screen, same height] ... but the `contentMode` fails me, it resizes the image it seems to that it fits on the screen!!]. I did a snapshot and I got this ...

[image]

Yes, it is a 3 & 4, but its the same as the 1 & 2.

The console is reporting?

```
19022017 previewPane 1920.0 1080.0 1920.0 1080.0
20022017 Optional(<UIImage: 0x60000009d9c0>, {1920, 768}) Optional(<UIImage: 0x60000009da10>, {1024, 768})
19022017 newimage  (0.0, 0.0, 1920.0, 1080.0) 1920.0 1080.0 (3840.0, 1080.0)
```

The `superNewImage` is 3840 wide and 1080 high, and I said just left justify it, but what is it doing?

If I load an image I created with Paint say that is the same size, and show it onscreen it works as I would have expected, half on screen, half off.

The original image I start with is here.

[image]

What I am looking to do is show only the first digit on screen so that the user of the app can scroll sideways to the second. The scrolling I got working, some fixing to do. And it works if I upload a preset image with the correct size [2 x width, same height]. But if I upload an image that is a subset, try and crop + combine it, no it doesn't work.

Just added a leftSide piece of code another whoops perhaps... still doesn't work. The first image I created the exact size worked, it looks like this ...

[image]

The original looks like this ...

[image]

Comment: ok - a little bit unclear what you are starting with, and what you are trying to end up with... Can you link to your original image, and how you expect it to finish? And, I assume your `cropImage()` func is the same as `self.chopImageFromRect()` ?

Comment: hmmm... your Original Image is `2048 x 768` yes? Do you want that non-proportionally scaled to `3840 x 1080`? Or, do you want it proportionally scaled to `2,880 x 1080` and then each half centered horizontally in each side of the final `3840 x 1080` image? Or, do you *not* want the image scaled, but instead center each half vertically and horizontally in each side of the final `3840 x 1080` image?

Comment: I want the image scaled so that it fits the AppleTV as two separate AppleTV screens. So a single image that is 3840 x 1080. I want that image to appear  on the screen initially as if it is only 1920 x 1080, giving the user the option to see the other half at 1920 x 1080 by scrolling across. I take the 2048 x 768, chop it in two (1024 x 768) resize the two half's and then combine them to one, ending up with an image 3840 x 1080. But when I show it on screen, I see both halfs at the same time, despite just using a contentMode of = left.

Comment: And yes, chop and crop are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing image size, desired image size, screen / view size...

Try this in a Playground... I added your 2048x768 "1 2" image named "orig2048x1024.png"

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

var screenSize = CGSize(width: 1920, height: 1080)

let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height))
containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green


func chopImageFromRect(image: UIImage, newRect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
    let img = CIImage(image: image)!.cropping(to: newRect)
    let image = UIImage(ciImage: img, scale: 1.0, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
    return image
}

func combine2LONGImage(imageUn: UIImage, imageDeux: UIImage) -> UIImage {

    let size = CGSize(width: imageUn.size.width + imageDeux.size.width, height: imageUn.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

    imageUn.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageUn.size.width, height: imageUn.size.height))

    imageDeux.draw(in: CGRect(x: imageUn.size.width, y: 0, width: imageDeux.size.width, height: imageDeux.size.height))


    let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage

}

func resizeLONGImage(image: UIImage, newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage!
}


var finalImage: UIImage?

// original image size is 2048 x 768
let image2S = UIImage(named: "orig2048x768.png")

// target image size should be 3840 x 1080
let targetImageSize = CGSize(width: screenSize.width * 2.0, height: screenSize.height)

if let sz = image2S?.size {

    // get the left side - x: 0 y: 0 / 1024 x 768 - of image
    let leftHalf = chopImageFromRect(image: image2S!, newRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sz.width / 2, height: sz.height))

    // get the right side - x: 1024 y: 0 / 1024 x 768 - of image
    let rightHalf = chopImageFromRect(image: image2S!, newRect: CGRect(x: sz.width / 2, y: 0, width: sz.width / 2, height: sz.height))

    // target size for each is Half of the Target Image Size (double the screen width x the screen height)
    let targetHalfSize = CGSize(width: targetImageSize.width / 2, height: targetImageSize.height)

    // scale each half to targetHalfSize
    let newLH = resizeLONGImage(image: leftHalf, newSize: targetHalfSize)
    let newRH = resizeLONGImage(image: rightHalf, newSize: targetHalfSize)

    // combine the two newly-scaled halfs
    finalImage = combine2LONGImage(imageUn: newLH, imageDeux: newRH)

    // create an UIImageView the same size as the screen
    let imgView = UIImageView(frame: containerView.bounds)

    // set contentMode to .left
    imgView.contentMode = .left

    // set the image of the image view
    imgView.image = finalImage

    // add the image view to the screen
    containerView.addSubview(imgView)

}


PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: Yes, maybe an error I never spotted! THANKS!! Changed it but sadly didn't fix it. Will update the question code too!!

Comment: Wait, I just seen another error in the code; I was reusing the original image, changed that an improvement, but its still not right. It has the height correct but not the width!!

Comment: Don, I found it; the leftImage was too big. It was in the trace. I check your answer too. If it works I mark it as the accepted answer as well! Thanks for your time!! Much appreciated. Corrected my code to a working copy too!!